# C# parsing to datetime regardless of culture info

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo, invariantculture

I have problem parsing some date string where language is not english. 
The sample date string is "8 avril 2016 vendredi" which is "8 april 2016 friday" in english.

I have tried this but no luck.

```
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParse("8 avril 2016 vendredi", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

In my case, date string can be in any language so I cannot specify the culture in parsing.
I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Unfortunately, CurrentCulture does not work.

Comment: Is there no way, based on other information related to the date, to get the culture? If not, I wonder if there is any possibility to do this, apart from iterating over every known culture and trying to parse it.

Comment: Where are your date strings coming from? I really dim it very difficult to fathom a culture-independent solution to parse culture-specific dates. You either need to know the specific culture beforehand, or get the date string in a culture-neutral format before parsing.

Comment: Maybe you could use `DateTime.ParseExact(...)` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat` as an `IFormatProvider`. This method let's you use many format strings.

Comment: Date strings are coming from scraped news around the world. So language cannot be identified beforehand.

Comment: @m.rogalski I cannot use ParseExact because date string can be in any format.

Comment: Which cultures do you need to support and which formats do you need to support?

Comment: You can't parse localized dates with the invariant culture so like it or not you need to specify a matching culture. The given date can be parsed with the "fr-FR" culture in .NET.

Comment: Culture and formats are unknown. If only it can be parsed same as how english date string is parsed.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to fiddle with HTML `<meta>` tags and/or HTTP headers (like `Accept-Language`), or maybe even author a lookup table `website => locale` to determine the date string's culture. Otherwise, try parsing each date with a predefined (preferably small) set of well-known cultures until you hit at least one that is able to successfully parse the date. Anyway, I don't think any approach would be 100% reliable.

Comment: Thanks, identifying the culture at first is the workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Behold, the terrible any parser!

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Select(culture => {
    DateTime result;
    return DateTime.TryParse(
        "8 avril 2016 vendredi", 
        culture, 
        DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out result
    ) ? result : default(DateTime?);
})
.Where(d => d != null)
.GroupBy(d => d)
.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
.FirstOrDefault()
.Key
```

This asks every culture on the system to parse the date, and picks the date that emerges most frequently as the "winner". It returns `null` if no culture could parse the date.

It isn't hard to think of ways this can fail to provide the correct result, because the most common result isn't necessarily the correct one and some dates are truly ambiguous. Is "04-05-2016" the fourth of May or the fifth of April? The any parser thinks the fourth of May is more likely simply because more cultures parse it that way. On my machine, at least. But that will not please American authors (who are overrepresented on the Internet), so maybe the probability of cultures needs to be taken into account.

This code should not be used to parse arbitrary user input, let alone all input, and even in the context of a scraper that truly lacks all other clues about the language, this is probably not the best approach. Also beware that this is slow; there are hundreds of cultures on an average machine. Guessing the whole culture for a page first and then consistently parsing based on that is absolutely a better idea.