# Convert any DateTime format to US DateTime format in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetime-format

I want to convert any DateTime format to US DateTime format i.e.

> MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss

I have the server date which can be anything like it can have `AM` / `PM` added in the tail too. I have to take care of most possible scenarios.

```
CodeValidTill = DateTime.ParseExact(dateObject.ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture);
```

I have also tried below method to cover most of the cases:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToUSDateFormat(string dateString)
{
     string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy", "MMM dd yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"};
     return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

Is there any way that we can write a generalized method to handle such situation?

Comment: So you want a method that can turn any string into a date?! So is 01/02/2018 1st of Feb or the 2nd of Jan?!

Comment: Dates do not have a format.  Formats are how Dates are displayed to humans.  Are you talking about parsing?

Comment: @Plutonix: yes. My bad. I am looking for parsing.

Comment: Parsing of what?  *I have to take care of most possible scenarios* this is impossible

Comment: "Is there any way that we can write a generalized method to handle such situation?" - no. As @Liam points out 2/2/18 is ambiguous

Comment: You must list ALL possible situations and write a method that can handle each. Just saying "it can be anything" isnt a problem you can solve with programming. For that you either need machine learning or magic

Comment: No. string representations of DateTime can't be parsed unless you know up front what format they are using. There is no way to know if `01/02/03` is February 1st 2003, January 2nd 2003 or even Match 2nd 2001.

Comment: If you are connecting to another computer the best way is using DataTime as an object.  The DateTime object is in UTF and is a number.  The you can display time in any format using the ToString() method.   Then you do not need to use ParseExact.  The straight Parse method can accept a number of different formats.  To solve this issue a long time ago the create the Universal Time String so everybody uses the same string format.

Comment: @jdweng a DateTime is not UTF - do you mean UTC? it may or may not be UTC

Comment: [You could always try all formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894251/4137916). I'm linking to this out of academic interest -- even though I wrote it myself, I recommend against actually using that code (and I outlined in the answer why it's not a good idea). You cannot truly cover *all* possible cases, due to the inherent ambiguity of some formats. Specifying a fixed, well-known list of formats you *are* willing to parse, like you're doing now, is absolutely a better choice. (The *best* choice is agreeing on *one* format, of course.)

Comment: I have edited the question to add another approach I have tried.

Comment: It should be clear that `""MM/dd/yyyy..."` and  `"dd/MM/yyyy"` (Edit) are going to confuse things quite often

Comment: Sorry,  I made a typo.

Comment: Ok, your not quite getting this. Given the extra code with all the formats, what date is 01/02/2018? It matches two formats `dd/MM/yyyy` and `MM/dd/yyyy`. Can you see why this isn't going to work?

Comment: @Liam, So can we handle it if we expect that date format will always be like `month-date-year time`?

Answer (score 1):

I have a number of hard and fast rules for dealing with DateTimes:

- Always store, retrieve and transmit the UTC value. You do not want to deal with Timezones. [That way lies madness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)
- Avoid storing, retrieving or transmitting them as Strings.
- If you can not avoid store/retreive/transmit as string, pick a fixed String Encoding and Format at all ends

If you follow all those rules you can somewhat reasonably work with DateTimes without going mad.

If you can not follow those rules, you should simply call it impossible so you can enforce the rules with a proper rework of the faulty code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. My case is nearly same. Here, I am receiving data from CRM and the field and value stored in `JObject` is - `"new_codevalidtill":"2018-02-01T05:00:00Z"`. But when I convert this JObject value to string, it parses it to my system date time format.

Comment: Both Parse() and ToString() have overrides that allow you to specify the Culture/Format to be used via a IFormatProvider instance. The largely Parameterless "Parse()" will simply call the complex one, using the current Culture as value (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx). CultureInfo are the terms you seek (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Agree with jdweng. Its a really good idea to store you dates as a DateTime. This object is format independent and can account for special cultural formats.

Example

```
DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 29); 
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d"));
```

This should display 1/29/2018

[More info on DateTime formatting with the "ToString" overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: So your point is turn the string into a date (somehow) and then turn it back into a string? Basically, your totally missing the point. If the OP had a date he wouldn't need to parse it at all.

Comment: No my point is to use a DateTime object when dealing with dates which is directly supported with a SQL database field. Frankly the question is ambiguous at best so my comment may be rather "scatter gun", however its best practice to use a DateTime and not store the value as a string.