# DateTime parse a list of cultures

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I am trying to parse a string with a date that might look like "17 Sep 2020", "17 Okt 2020", "17 10月 2020" or "17 十月 2020", so I am trying to parse a DateTime from a string that might have either English, Simplified Chinese, or German culture.
I can think of a few solutions, but they are very clunky, like trying to parse each culture one by one. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't see how there could be any other option besides "try each culture one at a time until it is valid". `TryParseExact` has an overload that accepts a list of formats (but only a single CultureInfo), and that's how it works under the hood.

Comment: @gunr2171 would that work with months written in Chinese characters? Or would I need to convert them to numbers manually?

Comment: Look at other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892469/c-sharp-parsing-to-datetime-regardless-of-culture-info

Comment: Be aware that the same date string might be valid in multiple cultures but still end up meaning different dates. You need some sort of order/priority.